# Why using @function (disabling error reporting per function) in PHP is bad practice?

Tags: php, function, error-handling

In PHP we can disable error reporting for particular function by using @ at the beginning of the function:

[Error Control Operators](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.errorcontrol.php)

> PHP supports one error control operator: the at sign (@). When
> prepended to an expression in PHP, any error messages that might be
> generated by that expression will be ignored.

for example:

```
@mail(...)
```

Will not return any error in case if there is one, **is that a bad practice? and why?**

Comment: If mail() fails you will never know why , why not just log all your errors , error_log will save you alot of pain

Comment: It does not disable error reporting. It just disables error/warning display for the default handler by temporarily resetting the reporting level.

Comment: Thanks for reply, I just asked this question intentionally, for clearing why this is a bad practice...

Comment: To those who will be tempted to vote for closing this question as "primarily opinion-based": that it is bad practice is not "opinion-based" but a widely recognised fact. Anyone who has worked in a real production environment (read: has debugged someone else's code) will agree. Read again: "Many good questions generate some degree of opinion based on **expert experience**".

Comment: why is sticking your head in the sand and ignoring problems bad practice in life ?

Comment: Thanks @RandomSeed: We all knew it's bad, there is no onion-based...

Comment: noting is 100% bad, there are circumstances when its not.

Comment: @Akam Absolutely. Onion-based discussions are definitely off-topic.

Answer (score 5):

Yes it is bad practice. This is mainly because it allows for lazy code writing, when you should be surfacing and correcting errors that you get rather than just suppressing them and then being surprised someday when your code doesn't work and you can't figure out why.

Answer (score 2):

The way you build your program should handle errors, not hide them.  If it's possible that a function is going to create an error, then you should code to handle that.  Here's an example.

Let's say I have an array called $myarray, and I want to loop through it:

```
foreach($myarray as $value) {
    print $value;
}
```

If the existence of $myarray is conditional (i.e. perhaps it's created from data being pulled from a database), then the foreach() loop will fail because $myarray is not a variable.  To handle that situation, I might write the above loop like this:

```
if(isset($myarray) && is_array($myarray)) {
    foreach($myarray as $value) {
        print $value;
    }
}
```

This will verify that the array actually exists before trying to execute the loop.  In this way, foreach() can't throw an error for this reason, and I didn't have to suppress any errors.

Potential errors should be avoided in the design of the code.  Unavoidable errors should be caught so that a useful non-geek message can be displayed to the user so that they know how to respond to the error.  Or better yet, if the program can circumvent the error and accomplish the task anyway and quietly, it should do that.

In the case of mail(), if it's going to throw an error, why would it do that?  Should you create a contingency for it, such as another method of sending the email, or queueing it for later delivery, or some other option?  You don't want to suppress the error, you want to handle it.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah it is a bad practice. For example an user wants to register on your site and you will send him an activation link or something important in the mail. You are using `@mail`, but the mail can not be send, because of an internal error(mail server down) or something like that. Will the user ever know, that the email wasn't sent? No, because you suppressed the error with the `@` or didn't handle the error and notified the user.

Answer (score 0):

There are some reasons that using PHP Error Control Operator `@` is bad:

**1- From PHP Manual**

> Currently the "@" error-control operator prefix will even disable
> error reporting for critical errors that will terminate script
> execution. Among other things, this means that if you use "@" to
> suppress errors from a certain function and either it isn't available
> or has been mistyped, the script will die right there with no
> indication as to why.

**2- You might still use Deprecated functions if you used `@` for example:**

```
if(eregi("a", "abc")) echo "a";
```

Produces this error:

```
 Deprecated: Function eregi() is deprecated in D:\htdocs\test.php on line 2
```

While using `if(@eregi("a", "abc")) echo "a";` not issues any message.

**3- Other facts:**

https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.errorcontrol.php#99805

> Be aware that using @ is dog-slow, as PHP incurs overhead to
> suppressing errors in this way. It's a trade-off between speed and
> convenience.

https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.errorcontrol.php#85042

> - the error handler that is set gets called regardless of what level the error reporting is set on, or whether the statement is preceeded
>   with @
> - it is up to the error handler to impart some meaning on the different error levels. You could make your custom error handler echo
>   all errors, even if error reporting is set to NONE.
> - so what does the @ operator do? It temporarily sets the error reporting level to 0 for that line. If that line triggers an error,
>   the error handler will still be called, but it will be called with an
>   error level of 0

https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.errorcontrol.php#94004

> Be aware of using error control operator in statements before
> include() like this:
>
> `<?PHP (@include("file.php"))  OR die("Could not find file.php!"); ?>`
>
> This cause, that error reporting level is set to zero also for the
> included file. So if there are some errors in the included file, they
> will be not displayed.

Finally, error handling can be managed centrally for all application not just for particular function.